# Single variable integration proof help?

Tags: calculus

My primary focus has been physics so my mathematics is somewhat amateur and I've done something I'm not quite sure if I'm allowed to do.  Can I say

$$\int f(x) \;\mathrm{d}g(x) = \int f(x) \frac{\mathrm{d}g(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\;\mathrm{d}x$$

I did so with the proof for E = mc^2 and I got the right answer, but I don't know if this is something I'm actually allowed to do.

Comment: You can find a lot about such integrals if you search for "Riemann-Stieltjes Integrals".

Comment: Thank you!  I'll look them up!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\int f(x) dg(x)= \int f(x)\frac{dg}{dx}dx$.  How you prove that depends upon how, exactly, you have **defined** $\int f(x) dg(x)$ for g a function of x.  With the most common definition, it reduces to a "substitution".

Comment: So I was attempting this with a different equation as well, and using WolframAlpha to solve.  My equation pre change yielded a logarithmic integral in the solution, but post change yielded no such thing.  Does this imply that the logarithmic integral was equal to zero? I'd post the integral but I'm still getting a feel for how formatting works.  The equation was the integral of 1/f(x) with respect to x.  I substituted it for df(x) which gave 1/(f(x)f(x)') with respect to f(x).